# Rails unless with 2 conditions, second condition not working using slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, conditional-statements, slim-lang

Here's my code:

```
- unless Relationship.are_friends?(current_user, @user) && (current_user != @user)
  - puts "d"*100
  - puts "#{current_user.inspect}"
  - puts "#{@user.inspect}"
  = link_to "Add Friend", controller: "relationships", action: "req", name: @user.name,      remote: true, class: "friend_link"
```

Basically the second condition "current_user != @user" is not working and I don't know why.  When I puts the current user and @user they are working correctly.  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name]).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is that how your code is actually indented? Assuming that's haml, nothing there is actually part of the `unless` statement.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry its .slim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is your requirement. Allow A to add B as a friend if:

- A and B are not already friends AND
- A and B are not the same person

So, in pseudo-code,
unless (already_friends or same_person)
  allow_add_friend
end

If this is your requirement, your statement should read:

```
unless Relationship.are_friends?(current_user, @user) or (current_user == @user)
```

Note that `&&` changed to `or` and `!=` changed to `==`.

Answer (score 1):

`unless` is often a bit counterintuitive, especially with multiple conditions. Look at it this way:

```
true && false # => false, code is executed
false && true # => false, code is executed
```

The only condition in which the block is skipped is:

```
true && true  # => true, code is not executed
```

I imagine what you're trying to do is skip the block is either condition is true, in which case you need to use the `||` operator:

```
unless Relationship.are_friends?(current_user, @user) || (current_user == @user)
  #etc..
```